# How to call double value from .h class in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have defined double variable for my .h class like this

```
double *i;
double *j; 
double *k;
```

Now I call that variable in my .m file like this

```
i = j+k;
```

but its showing error like this,

```
invalid operands to binary expression 'double' and 'double'
```

I'm new to iPhone and objective c environment guide me how can I call that.

Comment: double is of the Primitive Data Type .double is not a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Objective C is a superset of C. So primitive data types (int, float, double) remain primitive. Try without pointers:

```
double i;
double j;
double k;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable like this

```
double *i;
```

you are not declaring a double value, but a pointer to a double. Above the pointer is not pointing to any double value just yet.

```
double someValue = 123.0;
double *i = &someValue;   // now i points to a value
```

in Objective-C primitive types like double, int, char i.e. types that are not derived from NSObject are regarded as normal C types.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't take your variables as pointer in the .h file then you code will run absolutely fine. Give it a try.

```
double i;
double j;
double k;
```